# I want to search and find the location and weather details in weather map

Tags: c#, asp.net, google-maps, google-weather-api

I have added one text box and search button into this application.I want enter a location and click search button then it shows the appropriate location with weather details. I tried in many ways but won't works. So any one have the code, then please share with me.
Thank you.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>

<html>
  <head id="Head1" runat="server">
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title>Weather layer</title>


    <script src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?v=3.exp&libraries=weather"></script>
    <script>
        function initialize() {
            var mapOptions = {
                center: new google.maps.LatLng(12.9667, 77.5667),
                zoom: 6,
                mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.WeatherLayer
            };

            var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map-canvas'),
                mapOptions);

            var weatherLayer = new google.maps.weather.WeatherLayer({
                temperatureUnits: google.maps.weather.TemperatureUnit.FAHRENHEIT
            });
            weatherLayer.setMap(map);

            var cloudLayer = new google.maps.weather.CloudLayer();
            cloudLayer.setMap(map);
        }

        google.maps.event.addDomListener(window, 'load', initialize);

    </script>

  </head>
  <body>
      <form id="form1" runat="server">
    <div id="map-canvas"style="height:400px;width:400px;"></div>
  <asp:Button ID="Button1" runat="server" Text="Proceed" />
          <input id="searchTextField" type="text" size="50"style="height:auto;width:320px;">
          </form>
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: So where is the question? Semms like there were only 2 or less columns in the GridView

Comment: remember the columns are zero based

Comment: GridView1.Columns[2].Visible = false;

Comment: @Cheese I have 4 columns in gridview. I want to delete or hide one of the column on run time by clicking button.?

Answer (score 0):

Instead of removing your column, you can hide it by

```
protected void Button4_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{          
   GridView1.Columns[2].Visible = False;
}
```

However, since its giving you an `Index was out of range` exception, the third column might not exist in your grid. Seems like you want to hide the second column and so you should write

```
GridView1.Columns[1].Visible = False;
```

since the index of grid columns start from zero.